# FullCalendar Data from MySQL via JSON not pulled through

Tags: fullcalendar

Good morning, I have created a json file that displays event data from mysql, when viewed in browser it displays the table data ok.

When I try to view include this with fullcalendar script the calendar shows up but not the data, amk I missing something?

xxjson-events.php

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/ghl_portal.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal);
$query_rsXXCal = "SELECT * FROM events";
$rsXXCal = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsXXCal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsXXCal);
$totalRows_rsXXCal = mysql_num_rows($rsXXCal);
        $result = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal) or die(mysql_error());
        $arr = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
             $arr[] = $row; 
        }  
        echo json_encode($arr)
?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsXXCal);
?>
```

json.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            theme: true,
            draggable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'month, agendaWeek',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today, prev,next'
            },

            editable: false,

            allDayDefault: false,

            url: true,

            timeFormat: 'HH:mm ', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            agenda: 'HH:mm ', // 5:00 - 6:30

            events: "xxjson-events.php",


            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' ha sido movido ' + delta + ' dias\n' + '(should probably update your database)');

            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            },

            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                 //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                 //alert('Url: ' + calEvent.url);
                 //alert('View: ' + view.name);

                 window.open(calEvent.url, blank);
                 return false;

            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to do so Since version **1.5**

`events : {url: '/xxjson-events.php'}`

**Note:** `title: start: and end :` <-- these property must be in your json data

there are also many optional

[Reference](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the post. I edited events line in json.html, where about's would I add the title code & is the below code all I need to add into the file? 

   <code>title: start: and end :</code>

Comment: Hi again, afraid I didn't understand the last post, "update your question", are you able to clarify, sorry to ask?